# Redirect to another view with dictionary data in django

Tags: django, dictionary, django-views, http-redirect

I am getting some post data from wufoo service as json data, and i am receiving that from one of my view. Here i was already logged in to the site, but i was unable to get the user object from `request` object like `request.user` and getting as Anonymus User, so because of some reasons decided to send the data to another view as below

```
@csrf_exempt
def wufoo_post_data(request, form_hash):
    if request.method=='POST':
        post_data = request.POST
        wufoo_rfq_structure = WufooRFQStructure.objects.get(form_hash=form_hash)
        data = {'wufoo_rfq_structure':wufoo_rfq_structure, 'form_data':post_data}

    return redirect('add_user_to_rfqentry', data)

def add_user_to_rfqentry(request, data):
    print data
    return HttpResponse('OK')
```

But i was getting the error as

```
** NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'add_user_to_rfqentry' with arguments '({'form_data':.........},)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

So how to call another view with some data in django ?

Comment: Post your ```urls.py```. The issue is the call to ```redirect('add_user_to_rfqentry', data)``` which is doing a reverse match on ```'add_user_to_rfqentry'``` to find a named URL, and then looking for said named URL with given keyword arguments. I suggest looking at the docs for [```redirect()```](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)

Comment: actually i dint created the url structure, what my doubt is we can't redirect to another view directly by mentioning the view name and data instead of url config name ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add "add_user_to_rfqentry" to your urls.py if you want to do it that way. You can find the information in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/).

If you are going to redirect you HAVE to set your urls.py. In the other hand if all you want is to call another function you can do something like:

```
def wufoo_post_data(request, form_hash):
    ...
    return add_user_to_rfqentry(request, data)

def add_user_to_rfqentry(request, data):
    return HttpResponse('OK')
```

That is not a redirect, just a call to another function.